# help regarding combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to know if there is any good book or material that fully explains and fully covers all combinatorics.I even did not find even Kenneth H.Rousan for this.So can anyone tell me any Discrete Mathematics book or any material to fully  explain Combinatorics even to advance level.that provide classification to combinatorics problems(most important).

Comment: There is no book that covers "all combinatorics". Can you clarify what you are interested in? A nice book on (extremal) combinatorics is the one by Stasys Jukna.

Comment: I am interested in combination problems that contain-distribution of distinct/indistinct  objects to distinct/indistinct people,also with type of partition not defined,unordered partition etc advanced level problems

Comment: This is a math question, perhaps more appropriate in math.se.

Comment: Combinatorics is a vast subject, still healthily developing. There is no book covering all of combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

You say in a comment:

> I am interested in combination problems that contain-distribution of distinct/indistinct objects to distinct/indistinct people,also with type of partition not defined,unordered partition etc advanced level problems

It doesn't sound to me like you want a book that covers all of combinatorics. Combinatorics is a [vast subject,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) which includes enumerative combinatorics, probabilistic combinatorics, extremal combinatorics, graph theory, and several other subdisciplines. It sounds to me like you are interested in a subarea of *enumerative combinatorics*.

Richard Stanley's two-volume series on [enumerative combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/) is quite good, and I suspect it contains the material you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following book might be what you are looking for:

**Handbook of combinatorics**. Vol. 1 and 2. Edited by *R. L. Graham, M. Grötschel and L. Lovász*, Elsevier Science B.V., Amsterdam; MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, 1995. Vol. I: cii+1018 pp.; Vol. II: pp. i--cii and 1019--2198. ISBN: 0-444-88002-X